# Send @Output table results to a flat file in SSIS package returning 0 rows

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Hi and thank you for your help.

I have an SSIS package the first step of which executes a sql delete query to delete rows in a table and send the rows it deleted to @output table.  The next step tries to take the @output table and send it to a flat file destination.  When I ran the delete query in sql server mgmt. studio it successfully output the rows it deleted but for some reason the flat file in the package ends up with 0 rows.  Is there something I need to do to make the @output table data accessible in the subsequent flat file destination component?  Do I need to create a temp table instead?

Here is the query to output deleted rows in the table @output.  I'd like to take the contents of the @output table and send them to a flat file destination.

```
DECLARE @Output table
(PatientVisitID         INT`
,VisitNumber            NVARCHAR(45)`
,LastName               NVARCHAR(45)`
,FirstName              NVARCHAR(45)`
,MiddleName             NVARCHAR(45)`
,NamePrefix             NVARCHAR(45)`
,NameSuffix             NVARCHAR(45)`
,BirthDate              NVARCHAR(45)
,MedicalRecordNumber    NVARCHAR(45)
,Gender                 NVARCHAR(1)
,AdmitState             NVARCHAR(45)
,AdmitDateTime          NVARCHAR(45)
,DischargeDateTime      NVARCHAR(45)
,SSN                    NVARCHAR(12)
,PatientType            NVARCHAR(45)
,HospitalService        NVARCHAR(45)
,Location               NVARCHAR(45)
,DischargeDisposition   NVARCHAR(45)
)
DELETE 
FROM PatientVisits
OUTPUT 
DELETED.PatientVisitID 
,DELETED.VisitNumber            
,DELETED.LastName               
,DELETED.FirstName              
,DELETED.MiddleName             
,DELETED.NamePrefix             
,DELETED.NameSuffix             
,DELETED.BirthDate              
,DELETED.MedicalRecordNumber    
,DELETED.Gender                 
,DELETED.AdmitState             
,DELETED.AdmitDateTime          
,DELETED.DischargeDateTime      
,DELETED.SSN                    
,DELETED.PatientType            
,DELETED.HospitalService        
,DELETED.Location               
,DELETED.DischargeDisposition   
INTO @Output
where 
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 33  > cast(convert(varchar,AdmitDateTime,101) as   DATETIME)
AND PatientType NOT IN ('01','12')
SELECT * FROM @Output`
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try with temp tables -

Put this statement in a Execute SQL task, and set the connection manager's **RetainSameConnection to 'True'** (this will make sure the temp table will be visible in another tasks)

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##DeletedRows') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE ##DeletedRows
CREATE TABLE ##DeletedRows(EmpId TINYINT, EmpName VARCHAR(10))

  DELETE 
  FROM dbo.Emp
  OUTPUT
  DELETED.EmpId,
  DELETED.EmpName
  INTO ##DeletedRows
```

Next, use a Data flow task and set the Data flow task's **Delay Validation property to True**. Drop an OLE DB Source task and a Flat File Destination.

For first time, run this statement in db

```
CREATE TABLE ##DeletedRows(EmpId TINYINT, EmpName VARCHAR(10))
```

In the OLE DB Source, use the sql statement

```
SELECT * FROM ##DeletedRows
```

and the map the columns to your Flat file. Since we want to initially map the columns from OLE DB Source to Flat File, so we created the temp table in db. Since the Delay validation is set to True, so from next time we don't need to create the temp table manually.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have something awry with your data and/or your query.

Consider the following simplified demo

```
IF NOT EXISTS

(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        sys.schemas AS S
        INNER JOIN sys.tables AS T
        ON S.schema_id = T.schema_id
    WHERE 
        S.name = 'dbo'
        AND T.name = 'so_36868244'
)
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE dbo.so_36868244
    (
        SSN nvarchar(12) NOT NULL
    );
END

INSERT INTO
    dbo.so_36868244
(
    SSN
)
SELECT
    D.SSN
FROM
(
    VALUES
        (N'111-22-3333')
    ,   (N'222-33-4444')
    ,   (N'222-33-4445')
    ,   (N'222-33-4446')
) D(SSN)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.so_36868244 AS S
    ON S.SSN = D.SSN
WHERE
    S.SSN IS NULL;
```

We now have a table with a single column and 5 rows of a data.

I used the following query which uses the OUTPUT clause to push the DELETED data into an table variable and then selects from it

```
DECLARE
    @output table
(
    SSN nvarchar(12) NOT NULL
);

DELETE TOP (2) S
OUTPUT
    Deleted.SSN
INTO
    @output ( SSN )
FROM
    dbo.so_36868244 AS S

SELECT O.SSN FROM @output AS O;
```

Run that 3 times you'll end up with 2 rows, 2 rows and no rows. No problem, rerun the first query and you have 4 rows again - hooray for idempotent operations.

I used that query as the source for an OLE DB Source and then wrote the data to a flat file.

[image: Works fine]

### Reproduction

Biml, the business intelligence markup language, allows me to use a simplified XML dialect to describe an SSIS package. The following Biml, when fed through the Biml engine, will be translated into an SSIS package for whichever version of SQL Server you are working with.

Sound good? Go grab [BimlExpress](https://varigence.com/BimlExpress), it's free and install it for your version of SSIS.

Once installed, under the BimlExpress menu select "Add New Biml File". Paste the following

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
    <Connections>
        <OleDbConnection Name="tempdb" ConnectionString="Data Source=localhost\dev2014;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Provider=SQLNCLI11.0;Integrated Security=SSPI;"/>
        <FlatFileConnection FilePath="C:\ssisdata\so\output\so_36868244.txt" FileFormat="FFF so_36868244" Name="FFCM" />
    </Connections>
    <FileFormats>
        <FlatFileFormat Name="FFF so_36868244" IsUnicode="false" ColumnNamesInFirstDataRow="true" FlatFileType="Delimited">
            <Columns>
                <Column Name="SSN" DataType="String" Length="12" Delimiter="CRLF" />
            </Columns>
        </FlatFileFormat>
    </FileFormats>
    <Packages>
        <Package Name="so_36868244">
            <Tasks>
                <Dataflow Name="DFT Stuff">
                    <Transformations>
                        <OleDbSource ConnectionName="tempdb" Name="SQL Stuff">
                            <DirectInput><![CDATA[DECLARE
    @output table
(
    SSN nvarchar(12) NOT NULL
);

DELETE TOP (2) S
OUTPUT
    Deleted.SSN
INTO
    @output ( SSN )
FROM
    dbo.so_36868244 AS S

SELECT O.SSN FROM @output AS O;]]></DirectInput>
                        </OleDbSource>
                        <DerivedColumns Name="DER Placeholder"></DerivedColumns>
                        <FlatFileDestination ConnectionName="FFCM" Name="FFDST Extract" Overwrite="true" />
                    </Transformations>
                </Dataflow>
            </Tasks>            
        </Package>
    </Packages>
</Biml>
```

Edit lines 3 and 4 to be valid database connection strings (mine is using tempdb on a named instance of DEV2014) as well as point at a valid path on disk (mine is using C:\ssisdata\so\output)

Right click on the bimlscript.biml file and out pops a package named so_36868244 which should be able to run immediately and generate a flat file with contents like

```
SSN
111-22-3333
222-33-4444
```

### What's wrong with your example

Without access to your systems and/or sample data, it's *very* hard to say.

I will give you unsolicited advice though that will improve your development career. You should avoid shorthand notation like `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 33` It's unclear what the result will be and saves a negligible amount of keystrokes compared to `DATEADD(DAY, -33, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`

`cast(convert(varchar,AdmitDateTime,101) as DATETIME)` There are also far more graceful mechanisms of dropping the time portion of a date than this.

Answer (score -1):

You would need to make it a real (permanent) table.  Table variables and Temp tables created in one Execute SQL task, are not available in other Execute SQL tasks.

You can always drop the permanent table when you are done with it.

Comment: I want to formally say thank you to everyone who replied to my question.                                                                                              After reviewing all your feedback I ended up using a "permanent" table.  I can't say that was the only solution but it was the one that I was able to get to work.